Help painting home walls
I have tried to pain the walls of my house and the result is awful. Somehow some parts are getting flat while others are getting 'dotted'. I have tried to paint the wall a second and a third time, but I see that this is just getting worse. The flat part gets flatter and the dotted part gets more obviously dotted. The effect is not visible if look facing to the wall, but if you look from the side, it's horrible.
What am I doing wrong here?


Your issue is not evident from the posted picture.  Perhaps post a pic from farther away.

The only thing I see is a slight streak at the left side of the pic.

Are the walls in your home textured or perfectly smooth?  How are you applying paint - brush?  Roller?  Spray?  What type of brush, roller, or sprayer?
